# Why Maple can not evaluate this indefinite integral directly?

Tags: indefinite-integrals, maple

I want to evaluate this indefinite integral 
\begin{gather*}
\int \ln^2(x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2})d x,\qquad \text{ where  $a>0.$}
\end{gather*}
I know it is not so hard to evaluate this integral by hand, via using integration by parts, but I want to test if Maple can do this easily. So I  asked Maple. Below is the result:
[image: result given by Maple 2016]

As you can see, if I enter just the command line  >int(ln(x+sqrt(x^2-a^2))^2,x), Maple can not return the desired result, but just the command line itself.  But if I use IntTutor, then it works well. My question is, why Maple can not give the result directly?

Comment: What you asked and the integral you provided Maple are not the same.

Comment: So it seems that Maple is not availing itself of the obvious simplification $\ln(a^2)=2\ln(a)$. Really? ... I remember problems with Mathematica and integrals back 25 years ago.

Comment: @TedShifrin: It's $\ln^2(a),$ not $\ln(a^2).$

Comment: What was typed into the first line was not, and it seems that's what Maple is working on, @Lucian.

Comment: @TedShifrin Where do you see $\ln(a^2)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Funny how this brings us all staring like an accident. On the very first line: int(ln(...)^2,x) :P ... I haven't done Maple in a while, but for Mathematica, I would need to put parens around the ln(...) and then the ^2 for it to be the square of the ln.

Comment: This is the square of the log, not the log of the square.

Comment: OK ... Maple's convention is obviously different from what I'm used to. A bad convention, I would say.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have corrected the integrand.

Comment: Maple will not do student's homework.

Comment: I don't understand why Maple cannot calculate the integral directly, but once prompted to use IntTutor, it can calculate it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should belong to Mathematica.SE

Comment: What does it have to do with Mathematica?  Maple is not Mathematica.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, Mathematica 11 can do this fairly easily.

Answer (score 2):

Maple does not have a full implementation of the Risch algorithm (especially in the mixed transcendental-algebraic case, which is the most difficult), and therefore does not produce an elementary antiderivative in all cases where
such antiderivative exists.  It does try the Risch algorithm, but does not succeed.